# What is the pythonic way to achieve global variable use model

Tags: python, global-variables

I have multiple classes, modules and objects. Where most of them would need to access a set of constant variables (evaluated once at the begining then unchanged). I would like to know the "pythonic" way to do that.

My first idea was to let one class calculate them and use "global" in order to be able to access them from all other classes/modules. But I know that using global is discouraged in python. The other alternative is to use them as locals, but then I will have to pass the instance of the class to every other class in order to just use this small set of constants which seems like an overhead.

```py
class FirstClass():
    global run_constant
    run_constant =  # Some calculations to evaluate it for once, no need to change it later at all.
    # Many other methods and local variables


class SecondClass():

    def some_method():
        var_1 = run_constant * 2 # some operation that needs to read that constant, but no need to edit it


class ThirdClass():

    def some_method_again():
        var_1 = run_constant * 2 # some operation that needs to read that constant, but no need to edit it
```

My Second idea was to put the constants in a library, then import it and get that variable each and every time I need it, which seems like an overkill too. Because I will repeat the import statements many time. So,

```py
# In a separate module : constant_var.py

run_constant =  # Some calculations to evaluate it for once, no need to change it later at all.

# Then, in the other classes
import constant_var 

class SecondClass():

    def some_method():
        var_1 = constant_var.run_constant * 2 # some operation that needs to read that constant, but no need to edit it
```

What is the pythonic way to do it?

Comment: If they are _class_ attributes and not _instance_ attributes, other classes can refer to them as `FirstClass.foo`, without needing an instance of `FirstClass`, and without needing `global`.

Comment: If these values can really be set only once per process, making them attributes of a module (or of some object that is such an attribute) is appropriate.  Otherwise, you should be supplying them to every object that needs them, yes.

Comment: Hi Davis,
But the problem is that I will have to pass this object around to each and every other class that would use these values (and they are a lot).